# xmpp authenticate to face book chat api and always receive a failure

Tags: c++, xmpp, facebook-chat, gloox

I use the gloox open source API which works again several other XMPP servers.  I use the following code

```
 JID jid( "USERID@chat.facebook.com" );
  j = new Client( jid, "PASSWORD" );
  j->setServer("chat.facebook.com");
  j->setPort(5222);
  j->setSASLMechanisms(gloox::SaslMechPlain);
  j->setTls(gloox::TLSPolicy::TLSRequired);

  j->registerConnectionListener( this );
  j->registerMessageSessionHandler( this, 0 );
  j->disco()->setVersion( "messageTest", GLOOX_VERSION, "Windows" );
  j->disco()->setIdentity( "client", "bot" );
  j->disco()->addFeature( XMLNS_CHAT_STATES );
  StringList ca;
```

It connects and opens the tls socket but always receives a SaslNotAuthorized back from facebook.

Is my userID correct?   Am I missing something from facebook?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your Facebook Chat JID [here](https://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php), under "other" link.
- You no need to change any server, port, SASL or TLS parameters, set up only JID and password, XMPP library should find all other parameters automatically. Just tested with gloox and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you.  My issue was getting the correct JID to use in the login.  The link you provided was the piece of information I was missing.